VS Code jsconfig.json - Unable to Navigate to index.js for Certain Imports
I'm facing issues with VS Code navigation using a jsconfig.json configuration. Specifically, I want to correctly navigate to index.js files within directories and specific files.
src/
├── Foundation/
│   └── Config.js
├── Listeners/
│   ├── IndexListener.js
│   └── Concerns/
│       └── index.js
├── Platforms/
│   └── index.js
├── Services/
│   └── Consent/
│       └── index.js

My imports in my file are as follows:

// src/app/Listeners/IndexListener.js

import { Config } from 'Foundation/Config' // Should navigate to src/app/Foundation/Config.js
import { CreatesQuizCollection } from './Concerns' // Should navigate to src/app/Listeners/Concerns/index.js
import { Consent } from 'Services/Consent' // Should navigate to  src/app/Services/Consent/index.js
import { Platform } from 'Platforms' // Should navigate to src/app/Platforms/index.js

My Current jsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "Foundation/*": ["src/Foundation/*"],
      "Platforms/*": ["src/Platforms/*", "src/Platforms/*/index.js"],
      "Services/*": ["src/Services/*", "src/Services/*/index.js"],
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "var/build", "var/dist"]
}

Problem:
VS Code doesn't navigate correctly when I Ctrl+Click on these imports:
import { Platform } from 'Platforms';
import { traits } from 'Utils';
I've tried multiple configurations, but these paths don't resolve to the index.js files as expected. How can I set up my jsconfig.json so that VS Code navigates properly to both index.js and other specific files within directories?
